# Google Sheets: Reference a cell's visual value as a string, maintaining number format?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to return the exact plain text value of a cell reference, including the number format, instead of the underlying data?

For instance, if a cell's underlying value is `2000` and the number format setting formats it as `$2,000`, I'd like to pull that string (`$2,000`) into another cell as plain text (eventually for use in a concatenation). Currently, referencing that cell simply returns `2000`, omitting the `$` and `,`.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in Google Sheets. You'd have to manually recreate the number format in your formula. Typically, you'd use the TEXT function, e.g.,

`=TEXT(A2,"$#,#")`

-or-

`="Cost: "&TEXT(A2,"$#,#")`

...etc.